# C++ memcpy return value

Tags: c++, memcpy

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy C++'s `memcpy` takes three parameters: destination, source and size/bytes. It also returns a pointer.

> `void* memcpy( void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count );`

Why is that so? Aren't the parameters enough to input and copy data?

Am I misunderstanding something? The examples don't use the return value.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If a function has nothing specific to return, it is often customary to return one of the input parameters (the one that is seen as the *primary* one). Doing this allows you to use "chained" function calls in expressions. For example, you can do

```
char buffer[1024];
strcat(strcpy(buffer, "Hello"), " World");
```

specifically because `strcpy` returns the original `dst` value as its result. Basically, when designing such a function, you might want to choose the most appropriate parameter for "chaining" and return it as the result (again, if you have noting else to return, i.e. if otherwise your function would return `void`).

Some people like it, some people don't. It is a matter of personal preference. C standard library often supports this technique, `memcpy` being another example. A possible use case might be something along the lines of

```
char *clone_buffer(const char *buffer, size_t size)
{
   return memcpy(new char[size], buffer, size);
}
```

If `memcpy` did not return the destination buffer pointer, we'd probably have to implement the above as

```
char *clone_buffer(const char *buffer, size_t size)
{
   char *clone = new char[size];
   memcpy(clone, buffer, size);
   return clone;
}
```

which looks "longer". There's no reason for any difference in efficiency between these two implementations. And it is arguable which version is more readable. Still many people might appreciate the "free" opportunity to write such concise one-liners as the first version above.

Quite often people find it confusing that `memcpy` returns the destination buffer pointer, because there is a popular belief that returning a pointer form a function should normally (or always) indicate that the function might allocate/reallocate memory. While this *might* indeed indicate the latter, there's no such hard rule and there has never been, so the often expressed opinion that returning a pointer (like `memcpy` does) is somehow "wrong" or "bad practice" is totally unfounded.

Comment: i guess that returning something, rather than returning nothing, is more expensive in terms of performance, though?

Comment: @hanshenrik: For "heavy" return values it might be true, but for scalar return values the effect is either non-existent or negligible. Scalar values are typically returned in CPU registers, which means that from some low-level point of view functions *always* return something. From that point of view you simply make them return meaningful values instead of meaningless ones. Even for "heavy" return values the RVO and NRVO should be able to reduce the penalty to virtually nothing.

Comment: @AnT, `Even for "heavy" return values the RVO and NRVO should be able to reduce the penalty to virtually nothing.` In a perfect world, they "should". How true is this is practice at present?

Comment: @cp.engr Now compilers must support it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision
"Return value optimization is mandatory and no longer considered as copy elision"

Answer (score 14):

IIRC, in early versions of C there was no `void` return. So library functions which have been around long enough return *something* for legacy reasons, and this was the best they could come up with.

There are a bunch of functions in `string.h` which return the destination parameter: `memcpy`, `strcpy`, `strcat`. It's not very useful, but it does no harm (probably in many calling conventions doesn't even require an instruction to implement).

You might conceivably come up with a use: `char *nextbuf = memcpy(get_next_buf(), previous_buf+offset, previous_size-offset);` instead of `char *nextbuf = get_next_buf(); memcpy(nextbuf, etc);` Or something.

For comparison, `qsort` returns void. It could have been defined to return `base` on the principle of "return something, it might come in handy", but wasn't. `std::copy` rather more usefully returns an iterator to the *end* of the output range. For non-random-access iterators that might not be trivial, or even possible, for the caller to compute.

Answer (score 2):

By returning a value, an invocation of the memcpy function can be used as an r-value.

Comment: then why not simply make it return the resulting array instead of passing it as parameter?

Comment: "instead of passing it as a parameter" -- think about that for a few seconds.

Comment: Because you are responsible for creating the space space for the destination. memcpy doesn't create any new space.

Comment: Because memcpy() does not allocate new memory for the destination (i.e. it needs a pointer to allocated memory to be passed to it). btw...I have rarely found the need to avail myself of memcpy()'s return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the return into a void if you want to indicate that you aren't using it - eg:


    `(void) memcpy(mydest, mysrc, mybytes);`

Answer (score 0):

```
void *memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count);
//returns void * which can be assigned to another void array that can be used as int or char data type.
void *ret = new int[6];
ret = memcpy(newarr, arr, sizeof(int)* 5);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer.