# Does memcpy not throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memcpy

Hopefully there is a simple answer to this as it seems a simple question, however I have not been able to find any information on this on the interwebs.

In the following code snippet, Visual Studio complains of unreachable code at the line "delete bytes;"

```
try
{
   memcpy(bytes, other.bytes, count);
}
catch (...)
{
   delete[] bytes;
   throw;
}
```

Does memcpy not throw exceptions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ memcpy return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723686/c-memcpy-return-value)

Comment: Incidentally, the delete bytes line should actually be delete[] bytes.

Comment: Not necessarily - bytes could be a single struct...

Comment: In this case, @Jack is right, should have been delete[], how did I miss that?

Comment: @mgray88: You should then edit your question to fix that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. memcpy is a C function. It doesn't know about C++ features such as exceptions. (Of course, it's perfectly legal to use it in C++, although arguably not the best idea).

In response to karlphillip: I must indeed clarify my thoughts: in C++, memcpy should be used only for low-level buffer copies inside object private implementation. It shouldn't be used as mundanely as it was in C (for example to copy numbers arrays) because plain-vanilla buffers are now usually hidden inside class implementations. Classes that wrap arrays or other large amount of data (such as std::array) expose methods to manipulate their contents. And by the time I write this, Mark Ransom nicely summarized it ;-)

Comment: Is it just me or was memory management actually easier before such constructs as exceptions began to pop up and prevent deallocation?

Comment: What would you use in C++ to copy memory from one place to another?

Comment: @karlphillip, in C++ you try not to copy "memory" but copy objects instead; for that you use `std::copy`.

Comment: @John: manual resource management is certainly much harder in the presence of exceptions, which is why you should never do it. In C++, *all* dynamic resources should be managed by objects that release them in their destructor. Of course, some languages have exceptions but not deterministic destruction; use them at your peril.

Comment: @karlphillip I've seen quite a few situations when using `std::copy` to copy "memory" (that is, an array of char) was compiled into more efficient code than what was supplied in the C library's `memcpy()`.

Comment: I would love to see that assembly. I'll report back when I do.

Comment: People use C++ to write low-level code like device drives and embedded systems, and when they do, `memcpy` is a perfectly reasonable thing to call.

Answer (score 5):

Your `catch` block catches C++ exceptions. On your platform, `memcpy` is not defined to throw C++ exceptions, and your compiler knows it, so it correctly informs you that your `catch` block will never execute.

It's *allowed* for `memcpy` to throw C++ exceptions. The function's behavior is undefined for cases when either of the pointers doesn't point at a valid object. It's perfectly valid for the function to throw a C++ exception in that situation because undefined behavior means it's perfectly valid for it to do *anything*.

You might find that `memcpy` on your platform throws *OS* exceptions when you're reading or writing invalid memory. You could get an *access violation*, but the C++ `catch` block doesn't catch that kind of exception. Use [`__try` and `__except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx) for that. Better yet, analyze and edit your program to make sure you never get into such a situation in the first place. Then you don't have to worry about how any particular platform behaves.

Comment: "the C++ catch block doesn't catch that kind of exception"  Unless you compile with the evil, yucky `/EHa` (on Visual C++).

Answer (score 2):

No, memcpy does not throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

memcpy comes from C, which predates C++ exceptions, so no. You will never catch an exception that is thrown as a result of memcpy.